# Post/share to iOS/Android/WP Facebook/Twitter application from web page

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter

I would like the ability to share content/page URL to a mobile's native application from a webpage. At the moment very few mobile users appear to be signed into Facebook/Twitter through the website URL, but rather through the native application. This obviously creates a problem that I can't find a real solution for.

```
<a href="fb://">Facebook</a>
<a href="twitter://>Twitter</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yyqj7u6L/

Both these links open the native app on Facebook & Twitter (if installed), but don't appear to have the functionality to post a status/share content without manually typing in.

I have checked the documentation here 
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook
With no luck.

My other thought about this problem is to target the share ability built into most mobile browsers, for example on Chrome I have the option to share via Facebook and so on. Although very little seems to be available about launching this feature from within a web page? I guess there is some security issues with this.

I did have a good look on here to find similar solutions but nothing quite hit the spot, related directly to sharing to native app from web page.

Answer (score 2):

The code below should work for Twitter.

```
<a href="twitter://post?message=YOUR TEXT HERE" target="_blank">Share to Twitter</a>
```

Comment: Great thanks, this work a treat. I would +1 you but don't have enough rep yet.